# React Popper. How to move element relatively parent?

Tags: popper.js, react-popper

I'm trying to move Popper that is inside parent component. How i can do it?

I tried to use offset property in modifiers object.
e.g.:

```
offset: {
  offset: 20,
}
```

But offset only move Popper in one direction. If placement={'top' || 'bottom'} => it moves right and left, if placement={'right' || 'left'} => it moves top and bottom.

```
const Layer = ({
  children,
  align,
  inner = true,
  parent,
  portal,
}) => (
  <Manager>
    <Popper
      placement={align}
      modifiers={{
        inner: {
          enabled: inner,
        },
      }}
      referenceElement={parent}
    >
      {({ ref, style, placement }) => (
        <div
          ref={ref}
          data-placement={placement}
          style={style}
        >
          {console.log(style)}
          {children}
        </div>
      )}
    </Popper>
  </Manager>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just dealt with this: [Place MaterialUI Tooltip "on top" of anchor element? (React)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61112311/place-materialui-tooltip-on-top-of-anchor-element-react/)

```js
PopperProps={{
  popperOptions: {
    modifiers: {
      flip: { enabled: false },
      offset: {
        enabled: true,
        offset: '20px 20px'
      }
    }
  }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like that. Added `topOffset` and `leftOffset` props to popper child and used spread syntax. Don't think it is cleanest solution.

```js
const Layer = ({
  children,
  align,
  inner = true,
  parent,
  portal,
  topOffset,
  leftOffset,
}) => (
  <Manager>
    <Popper
      placement={align}
      modifiers={{
        inner: {
          enabled: inner,
        },
      }}
      referenceElement={parent}
    >
      {({ ref, style, placement }) => (
        <div
          ref={ref}
          data-placement={placement}
          style={{
            ...style,
            top: style.top + topOffset,
            left: style.left  + leftOffset,
          }}
        >
          {console.log(style)}
          {children}
        </div>
      )}
    </Popper>
  </Manager>
)
```